# Cover Letter Template

Tags: letters

I am trying to use [Matthew J. Miller's](http://www.matthewjmiller.net/howtos/customized-cover-letter-scripts/) cover letter template -

The PDF looks like [this](http://www.matthewjmiller.net/files/cover_letters/cover_example.pdf); however when I typeset the [template](http://www.matthewjmiller.net/files/cover_letters/cover_example.tex) at the first instance, I see that the date is misplaced and I am not able to figure out the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't find any hint in the `newlfm` documentation about that particular placement for the date; the only available options are `left` (the default) and `right`, but none of those will place the date aligned with the `\namefrom` block; one possible solution would be to use the `dateno` class option to suppress the date that is automatically included and then, include it manually using the `\namefrom` block:

```
\documentclass[10pt,stdletter,dateno]{newlfm}
```

and then:

```
\addrfrom{\today\\[20pt]%
    439 Coordinated Science Laboratory\\
    1308 West Main Street\\
    Urbana, IL 61801
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The handling of the date in that template isn't great. I feel like the document class *letter* is much better. A nice reference can be found here:

http://brunogirin.blogspot.com/2009/02/using-latex-letter-document-class.html